# Not receiving SMS when sending it through SNS in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sms, amazon-sns

I am sending the OTP using AWS SNS service when in a lambda function my code is this

```
  const otp = generateOTP();
  const message = `Your XXXX Verification Code is ${otp} .`;
  var params = {
    Message: message,
    PhoneNumber: "+91xxxxxxxxxx",
  };

  AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-south-1'});

  var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2022-04-01'}).publish(params).promise();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      publishTextPromise.then((data) => {
          console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
          const response = {
              statusCode: 200,
              headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(data)
          };
          console.log('Server response function');
          resolve(response);
      }).catch((error) => { reject(Error(error)); });
  });
```

and i am getting this response when invoking this lambda function

```
Server response function
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "ResponseMetadata": {
            "RequestId": "29796d67-f32e-5e42-a761-37a72809164d"
        },
        "MessageId": "2f8ffee0-7e0d-5cd3-a5b0-a420a52a14dc"
    }
}
```

But I am not receiving the SMS on that number I don't know what is the problem here cause the I am getting resolved response in the console which means the SMS is send but I am not received it.
Do I have to config the sns manual in aws sns mobile -> text messaging or something??
or is their any other way to send verification otp ?

Comment: You can **turn on delivery logs** to obtain detailed delivery information. See: [Access Amazon SNS topic delivery logs for SMS messages](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/)

Comment: yes it's an option, But I am sending directly to a number not the topic so??

Comment: **Delivery status logging** works for _any_ SMS messages that are sent, including those _not_ sent via a Topic, see: [Viewing Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html)